# Duplicate removal based on two fields while keeping the lowest value in the third field

Tags: text, awk, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicates in the txt file that contain the three columns. The duplicates are the one having identical "id" and "descr", and I need to keep only the lowest value.

```
id1 descr1  0.9
id1 descr1  1.23
id1 descr1  0.3
id1 descr2  0.5
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr3  1.2
id3 descr3  14.3
id3 descr3  0.5
id3 descr3  0.34
id3 descr4  4.5
```

so, I would like to recieve the following

```
id1 descr1  0.3
id1 descr2  0.5
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr3  0.34
id3 descr4  4.5
```

Right now, I have the following trick

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3n file.txt
```

and how to take the first occurence of the field1+field2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -k 3 < File | awk '!a[$1" "$2]++'
```

**Sample:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat File
id1 descr1  0.9
id1 descr1  1.23
id1 descr1  0.3
id1 descr2  0.5
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr3  1.2
id3 descr3  14.3
id3 descr3  0.5
id3 descr3  0.34
id3 descr4  4.5
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ sort -k 3 < File | awk '!a[$1" "$2]++'
id1 descr1  0.3
id3 descr3  0.34
id1 descr2  0.5
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr4  4.5
```

Though this doesn't match your expected output exactly, i hope this is enough for you.

First we sort based on 3rd field, this gives below output:

```
id1 descr1  0.3
id3 descr3  0.34
id1 descr2  0.5
id3 descr3  0.5
id1 descr1  0.9
id3 descr3  1.2
id1 descr1  1.23
id3 descr3  14.3
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr4  4.5
```

Now we are deleting the lines containing same `first and second` fields. For that we r using array `a` with index as `$1space$2`. Since we are incrementing `a[$1" "$2]` the first time, next occurrence of same `first and second` fields will be ignored, since `a[$1" "$2]` will not be 0 and hence `!a[$1" "$2]` will be false.

Comment: You should add some space or separator between `$1` and `$2`.  I have seen it fail if not (depending of the input data). Some like `awk '!a[$1FS$2]++'` or `awk '!a[$1" "$2]++'`

Comment: Can you please explain '!a[$1$2]++' part?

Comment: @JohnAmraph The `'!x[$0]++'` is a way to remove duplicate line in  `awk`.  Do a Google search for `awk remove duplicate` and you will find some explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You like some like this:

```
awk '{s=$1 FS $2;a[s]=a[s]<$3&&a[s]?a[s]:$3} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
id1 descr1 0.3
id2 descr2 23.1
id1 descr2 0.5
id3 descr3 0.34
id3 descr4 4.5
```

or some sort:

```
awk '{s=$1 FS $2;a[s]=a[s]<$3&&a[s]?a[s]:$3} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort
id1 descr1 0.3
id1 descr2 0.5
id2 descr2 23.1
id3 descr3 0.34
id3 descr4 4.5
```

Comment: Might want to change `&&a[s]` to `&&(a in s)` as it can be zero and not update :)

Comment: @Jidder I have not seen it done this way before and `(a in s)` gives this error: `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=t FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array 'a' in a scalar context`

Comment: meant `(s in a)` sorry!

Comment: @Jidder If I did use `(s in a)` I do not get any data output.

Comment: try `(s in a)&&a[s]<$3` instead of `a[s]<$3&&(s in a)`

Answer (score 0):

Using sort only:

```
~$ sort -t' ' -k4n myfile|sort -k1,2 -t' ' -u
```

---

First, sort using the 4th field numerically (using space as a separator, the numbers are the on 4th field since there are 2 consecutive spaces before them):

```
~$ sort -t' ' -k4n myfile
id1 descr1  0.3
id1 descr1  0.9
id1 descr2  0.5
id3 descr3  0.34
id3 descr3  0.5
id1 descr1  1.23
id3 descr3  1.2
id3 descr4  4.5
id3 descr3  14.3
id2 descr2  23.1
```

Then remove duplicate lines for the 1st and 2nd fields with `-u`:

```
~$ sort -t' ' -k4n myfile|sort -k1,2 -t' ' -u
id1 descr1  0.3
id1 descr2  0.5
id2 descr2  23.1
id3 descr3  0.34
id3 descr4  4.5
```